# I deployed an contract , have total supply but no token holder

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

interface BEP20 {
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function getOwner() external view returns (address);

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

interface Accounting {
    function doTransfer(address caller, address from, address to, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
}

contract MetaverseINU is BEP20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address public owner = msg.sender;    
    string public name = "MetaverseINU";
    string public symbol = "MINU";
    uint8 public _decimals;
    uint public _totalSupply;
    
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private allowed;
    address private accounting;
    
    constructor() {
        _decimals = 9;
        _totalSupply = 1000000 * 10 ** 9;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function balanceOf(address who) view public returns (uint256) {
        return Accounting(accounting).balanceOf(who);
    }
    
    function allowance(address who, address spender) view public returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[who][spender];
    }

    function setAccountingAddress(address accountingAddress) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        accounting = accountingAddress;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, address(0));
        owner = address(0);
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint amount) public returns (bool success) {
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, amount);
        return Accounting(accounting).doTransfer(msg.sender, msg.sender, to, amount);
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint amount) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(amount);
        emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
        return Accounting(accounting).doTransfer(msg.sender, from, to, amount);
    }
        
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
    enter code here

}
```

Comment: Please, can you explain better your issue?

Comment: So I deployed this contract, it's BEP-20, everything seems to be fine, but the total supply of tokens (1 million) are supposed to go to my wallet when I deploy the contract, in fact the transaction is there showing that 1 million tokens were transferred from null address to my wallet but on bsc scan the token says there are no holders and my wallet also don't show the tokens there, altought it shows the transaction!  (Sorry for the bad english)

Comment: Can you share hash about this transaction?

Comment: Sure: 0x4fd3968cf1109339cbd59d1ef6f8ed6f61405c1dcaf0b3ff34e6822d77d5aa48

Comment: Btw this is on testnet so the hash neede to be seen on bsc scann testnet